# Capture information from Google Site (inner HTML - think so)

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on Google Site

HTML

```
Customer:<a id="element1" onClick="javascript:changeText(1)">Yes</a>
Support:<a id="element2" onClick="javascript:changeText(2)">Yes</a>
EDC:<a id="element3" onClick="javascript:changeText(3)">Yes</a>
Ex 1:<a id="element4" onClick="javascript:changeText(4)">Yes</a>
Ex 2:<a id="element5" onClick="javascript:changeText(5)">Yes</a>
Ex 3:<a id="element6" onClick="javascript:changeText(6)">No</a>
Ex 4:<a id="element7" onClick="javascript:changeText(7)">No</a>
```

Javascript

```
function changeText(idElement) {
var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2 || idElement === 3
   || idElement === 4 || idElement === 5 || idElement === 6
   || idElement === 7) {
    if (element.innerHTML === 'Yes') element.innerHTML = 'No';
    else {
        element.innerHTML = 'Yes';
    }
}

}
```

The above [part](http://jsfiddle.net/UfVAH/366/) works fine...but I need to do refresh to update the charts that I have linked to the Yes, No, once refreshed all the Yes No gets restored as per HTML.

I searched (and even tried) using

```
var inner = document.getelementid("element7").innerhtml
```

But how do make it work. Basically I need to capture the value that were available on the site after refresh as well.

Comment: What Google has to do with this?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention....My site is on Google Site....amended

Answer (score 1):

That's just a suggestion. Of course you'll need to work on the solution based on your own requisites.

Basically you have a variable holding the default values and, when posting somehow, you can both see what was selected and restore the options to their original state.

**UPDATED**

**HTML**

```
Customer:<a id="element1" onClick="javascript:changeText(1)">Yes</a>
Support:<a id="element2" onClick="javascript:changeText(2)">Yes</a>
EDC:<a id="element3" onClick="javascript:changeText(3)">Yes</a>
Ex 1:<a id="element4" onClick="javascript:changeText(4)">Yes</a>
Ex 2:<a id="element5" onClick="javascript:changeText(5)">Yes</a>
Ex 3:<a id="element6" onClick="javascript:changeText(6)">No</a>
Ex 4:<a id="element7" onClick="javascript:changeText(7)">No</a>
<br />
Criteria applied: <input type="text" id="criteria" name="criteria" />
<br />
<button onclick="selection()">Selection</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

**JS**

```
var yesNoDefaults = ['Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'];

function changeText(idElement) {
    var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
    element.innerHTML = (element.innerHTML === 'Yes' ? 'No' : 'Yes');
}

function refresh() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
        document.getElementById('element' + i).innerHTML = yesNoDefaults[i - 1];
}

function selection() {
    var selection = '';

    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++)     
        selection += document.getElementById('element' + i).innerHTML + ',';

    selection.substring(0, selection.length - 1);

    document.getElementById('criteria').value = selection;

    refresh();
}
```

Check the example: http://jsfiddle.net/UfVAH/369/

Comment: Thanks MelanciaUK you have given me some wings, how to I acheive [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UfVAH/368/), basically a list of what was selected in the Critera Applied list.

Comment: Thanks...this is somewhat to what I was wanting, I have votedup as this is really helpful. Once this is resolved (I would still need to apply my thoughts) I will accept it as well... THANKS..